# Hibernate - Version property invokes automatic update on change?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

When retrieving entities and manipulating some of their properties programmatically an automatic update is invoked, with no manual call to `session.update()` by hibernate on commit incrementing my db-generated version column. (Even validation takes place).
I was surprised about my high version values and validation.

**Hibernate 4.3.1**

The entities are still attached to the session.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
Session session = sessinFactory.openSession();
Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();

Entity entity = session.get(Entity.class, 1);

entity.setFoo("foo");

tr.commit();
session.close(); // here fake-update takes place
```

**Question:**

Is this a feature?

I could try to detach instances that i am going to manipulate.

Or is this a bug? For me its more a bug, since I did not invoked an update. But not an fake-update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a feature.When `tr.commit()` is called, the session is flushed. Each object associated with the session is checked to see if it is 'dirty'(has changed state). Each changed object would be persisted to database irrespective of explicit save was called or not. Also, Hibernate will automatically increment version property during flush if the entity is dirty.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I just did not saw the changes in the database since the column i modified was marked not updatable.